# When I copy something from another window and do "+gP gVim says 'Nothing in register g'?

Tags: vim

When I copy something from another window and do `"+gP` gVim says 'Nothing in register g'
but when I go to Edit_>Paste it does paste the text from the another window.

I'm using ubuntu 10.10.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register you want to use is not g but +. So it looks like the +-sign is ignored/not typed at all.

`:reg` shows you the register-content.